# How to check if any fields in a form are empty in php

Tags: php, html, forms

whenever I submit something in my form i want to check if any of the fields are empty.  So far what I have is not working

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordconf = $_POST['passwordconf'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$securityq = $_POST['securityq'];
$qanswer = $_POST['qanswer'];

if(empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($passwordconf) || empty($email) || empty($securityq) || empty($qanswer))
{
    echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}
```

and the form

```
<form name="registrationform" action="register.php">
    First Name:<input type="text" name="firstname">
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname">
    Email:<input type="text" name="email">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username">
    Password:<input type="password" name="password">
    Confirm Password:<input type="password" name="passwordconf">
    Security Question:<input type="text" name="securityq">
    Answer:<input type="text" name="qanswer">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

and heres the registation page if it helps http://www.myjournal.tk/register.html

Comment: have you tried isset($_POST['field_name']) && ($_POST['field_name']!='')   ?

Comment: What does "what I have is not working" mean? Does it give you an error? Does it give you incorrect results? It will greatly help you to learn to [ask good questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) if you want good answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

your form is missing the method...

```
<form name="registrationform" action="register.php" method="post"> //here
```

anywyas to check the posted data u can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)..

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

```
if(!isset($firstname) || trim($firstname) == '')
{
   echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}
```

Comment: An empty string is considered [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: tried this and its still giving me an error

Comment: with provided link i can see are posting your from with GET method.. and you are trying to get the posted varible as POST in your server side...try it with  POST.... see my first answer

Comment: wait, for some reason it didnt update when i reuploaded my register.html i'll try again

Comment: yeah, ill have to figure that out but for now use <http://www.myjournal.tk/register2.html>

Comment: IT WORKED!!! thank you so much! ive been trying to figure it out for a  very long time now

Comment: welcome.. cheers.. have fun coding... :)

Comment: Don't forget to put `exit();` after `echo` statement. It will simply prevent the script executing further.

Answer (score 2):

```
Specify POST method in form
<form name="registrationform" action="register.php" method="post">


your form code

</form>
```

Comment: @SztupY - Actually, it does. This is the correct answer.